# Updating 600k rows, most of the columns are Varchar2(45). This update is taking too long ( 30 minutes ). Is there a better way to write the update?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

--Update address fields in address table with corrects address

the columns in the temp table are columns from address table and to be modified columns in address table. This update takes 30 minutes which will not work for our prod environment. How can i write this code to make it run faster?

```
DECLARE
       --Fetching data from temp table created for address update
       CURSOR My_Cursor
       IS
            --Fetching records which have a valid error code which is 2,4,5,20,46
            SELECT A.*
              FROM Fix_Dba.Temp_Address_Cleanup A, Fix_Dba.Addresses B
             WHERE A.Address_Id = B.Address_Id
          ORDER BY A.Address_Id;

   TYPE Plt_Cursor IS TABLE OF My_Cursor%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   Plt_Cursorarr     Plt_Cursor;            --Array declaration for the cursor

   --Track the address_ids which are not found in address_table
   CURSOR Record_Not_Found
   IS
        SELECT A.Address_Id
          FROM Fix_Dba.Temp_Address_Cleanup A
         WHERE A.Address_Id NOT IN (SELECT B.Address_Id
                                      FROM Fix_Dba.Addresses B)
      ORDER BY A.Address_Id;

   --declaring counter to commit records at certain intervals
   Counter           NUMBER := 0;
   V_Address_Id      NUMBER := 0;
   V_Err_Message     VARCHAR2 (5000);
   V_Efacts_Log_Id   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   OPEN My_Cursor;                                               --Open cursor

   FETCH My_Cursor BULK COLLECT INTO Plt_Cursorarr; --Fetching data which is required to update address fields

   CLOSE My_Cursor;

   IF Plt_Cursorarr.COUNT = 0 --Return if the count is zero and there are no records to process
   THEN
      RETURN;
   END IF;

   FOR I IN Plt_Cursorarr.FIRST .. Plt_Cursorarr.LAST --For loop declaration to update records
   LOOP

      BEGIN
         --Updating address fileds in address table after fetching correct data from temporary tables
         UPDATE Fix_Dba.Addresses A
            SET A.Address1 = Plt_Cursorarr (I).Address1_New, --Updating address line 1
                A.Address2 = Plt_Cursorarr (I).Address2_New, --Updating address line 2
                A.City = Plt_Cursorarr (I).City_New,           --Updating city
                A.State_Code = Plt_Cursorarr (I).State_Code_New, --Updating State
                A.Zip_Code = Plt_Cursorarr (I).Zip_Code_Addon, --Updating Zip code
                A.Update_Date = SYSDATE,
                A.Sysuser_Id_Updated_By = 1,
                A.Update_Source = 'LOG17690'
          WHERE A.Address_Id = Plt_Cursorarr (I).Address_Id; --Where clause for update

         Counter := Counter + 1; --Increment the counter to account for number of records

         IF MOD (Counter, 10000) = 0
         THEN                                    -- Commit every 10000 records
            COMMIT;
            Counter := 0; --Putting the counter value back to zero so that the counter for commit can restart
         END IF;
      EXCEPTION      --Handling exceptions... do we need to track address_ids?
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            V_Err_Message := 'ERROR: ' || SQLCODE || ';' || SQLERRM;
            Fix_Dba.Dbpc_Blaster_Inserts.Write_Log (
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               17690,
               'ADDRESS',
               V_Err_Message,
               'E',
               'AddressID',
               Plt_Cursorarr (I).Address_Id,
               V_Efacts_Log_Id);

      --           DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line ('Updated ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows.');
      --           DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line ('Error occurred with error code: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (I).ERROR_CODE);

      END;
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;

   BEGIN
      OPEN Record_Not_Found;

      LOOP
         FETCH Record_Not_Found INTO V_Address_Id;

         EXIT WHEN Record_Not_Found%NOTFOUND;

         V_Err_Message := 'Address Id not found';
         Fix_Dba.Dbpc_Blaster_Inserts.Write_Log (NULL,
                                                 NULL,
                                                 NULL,
                                                 17690,
                                                 'ADDRESS',
                                                 V_Err_Message,
                                                 'E',
                                                 'AddressID',
                                                 V_Address_Id,
                                                 V_Efacts_Log_Id);
      END LOOP;

  CLOSE Record_Not_Found;


 END;
END;
/
```

Comment: Try using `FOR ALL` to update inplace of loop.

Comment: `update` is one of the most basic operations in plain SQL. Why do you need a procedure for this, and not a plain SQL `update` statement? I understand you are updating the address columns (more than one column) with new data. Is the "old" data in a table stored in the database? I assume it is. Where does the "new" data reside - where is it coming from? Please don't ask us to read your code in order to find the answer to all these questions - just explain the setup in plain English, not through code.

Comment: How do i capture the exception if the update fails if i use FORALL?

Comment: Both tables are in the same schema. I need to capture the exception if the update statement fails. Even though the above code works, it is too slow.

Comment: Address_id is the key to the address table. If the key is not found, i need to log it. I understand that we can do just plain update but i wouldn't have a log of what failed and why it failed.

Comment: @user3263715. Look for `SAVE EXCEPTION` usage while using `FOR ALL` updates. You can get the exception incase update fails

Comment: @XING Thank you for your comment. I will look into that.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the update via a single MERGE statement, e.g.:

```
MERGE INTO fix_dba.addresses tgt
  USING fix_dba.temp_address_cleanup src
    ON (tgt.address_id = src.address_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.address1 = src.address1_new,
             tgt.address2 = src.address2_new,
             tgt.city = src.city_new,
             tgt.state_code = src.state_code,
             tgt.zip_code = src.zip_code_new,
             tgt.update_date = SYSDATE,
             tgt.sysuser_id_updated_by = 1,
             tgt.update_source = 'LOG17690';
```

If you are concerned about logging errors, you could always use [DML error logging](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2) to capture errors (although there are restrictions on this). However, I would hope that any constraints you have on your addresses table are also on your cleanup table, so the data should be ok to merge as is.